# Tips for a complete beginner to handle MOSFETs

Tags: mosfet

I've been reading up on MOSFETs and would like to try building my own small circuits, like amplifiers/CMOS logic gates using them on breadboards.

All the books I've been referred to have circuit diagrams but not a lot of information about actually using them in real circuits. I've read about MOSFETs being used to drive very high currents, so I'd rather be safe than sorry.

Some specifics I'd like to know are:

1. The types/models of MOSFETs I should be using (and avoiding)
2. Precautions I should be taking while handling MOSFETs.

Comment: The answer to #1 depends on exactly what you are trying to do with them. (Your system or circuit specs.)  The answer to #2 is easily found by literally copying your words into Google.

Comment: 1) on a breadboard "very high currents" isn't something that's going to work (too high contact resistance). Also high current MOSFETs generally have thick pins that might not fit in a breadboard. 2) The high current can only flow if there is something that will **deliver** a high current, for example a power supply. If you use current limited supply (like to 0.5 A) then "high current" cannot be an issue. 3) Ignore the "high current" MOSFETs, start with the 2N7000 NMOS for example.

Comment: Know that you can even drive an LED directly (with a series resistor) from the output of most CMOS logic gate ICs (4000 series, 74HC, 74HCT etc) so you might not even need a discrete MOSFET. If you want to power a relay or small motor, maybe the 2N7000 can already do that.

Comment: @John D For starters, I'd like to try building my own logic gates with MOSFETs.

Comment: Get an anti-static setup (antistatic desktop surface or rollup mat, wrist strap and earthing cable), and make sure your soldering iron is static safe.

Answer (score 2):

If you are interested in duplicating some of the internal circuits you might see in ICs, keep in mind that *analog* circuits used in ICs usually make frequent use of the close matching of transistors manufactured on the same die, so individual parts will tend to cause you unnecessary problems.

While matched transistors (where you can even buy them) tend to be quite expensive since they're used in rather specialized applications, there's an option for playing with such parts- use some inexpensive [CD4007UB](https://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/cd4007ub.pdf) chips.

[image]

You might only be able to use a couple transistors in a given configuration, but that's still a big win if they need to be matched.

Individual (eg. TO-92 or SOT-23) MOSFETs tend to be relatively high current and therefore high capacitance and slow. 2N7000/2N7002 and BSS84 are a couple that are medium current rating. One consequence of such parts is that if you make a CMOS inverter or gate with them, the shoot-through current during switching will be quite high. You'd be better to use CD4xxx or 74HCxxx gates.